# Can I use jQuery UI Autocomplete functionality, but replace the drop down display?

Tags: jquery-ui

Is it practical to use the jQuery UI Autocomplete as a base for a control that is functionally equivalent (in terms of the search functionality, results returned, etc...) but that displays the results in a fundamentally different way. I suspect the details of what sort of display don't really matter here, not a single column vertical list at any rate, but I can edit if people think that those details matter.  The main issue is, is it reasonably easy to override the display mechanism without altering the jQuery UI source?

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: @Matthew: I think the answer is probably not. The autocomplete widget uses an internal `menu` widget (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.menu.js), which is represented by an unordered list `ul`. I would draw the line at customizing the contents of each list item inside that unordered list. If you are feeling adventurous, you can dig into the widget source code (it's not that bad!): https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks, not the answer I wanted, but at least it gives me some confidence I won't be reinventing the wheel needlessly.  I will take up your challenge and dig into the code base and see what underlying libs and knowledge I can take advantage of.

Comment: @Matthew: Look specifically at the `_renderMenu` and `_renderItem` functions. These are what control the look of the dropdown menu, and they should be easily overridable without modifying the guts of autocomplete.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks that sounds promising.  You sure you don't want to post an answer?

Comment: @Matthew: I would, but I was hoping someone more knowledgeable might come along. I'll keep an eye on this question (and think about ways to change the display).

Comment: @Matthew: Also, what exactly is the design for your autocomplete mechanism? If you could at all leverage an unordered list (even if you have to change the style, move it around, etc), you might be able to accomplish this.

Comment: @Andrew: The design is basically to display normally if the list is up to a certain length and if it above that length to display a 3 or 4 column list of the letters of the alphabet with the number of entries that start with that letter next to the letter.  If you select one of the letters it expands to show the entries starting with the letter.  I haven't prototyped it yet so I may be leaving something out.  I believe there is something similar in the Windows Phone 7 UI.

Answer (score 0):

@Matthew,  while I am not sure how much it applies to what you are trying to do, as I do not know your end game, angularjs and angularUI are both pretty useful for doing filtering on data based off a text field.  You can organize it in pretty much any fashion you want and tie it to a variety of data sources.

I've used it in place of auto complete on product listing pages to help filter down without page re-loads.